# fonts won't load onto mobile device

Tags: css

I was testing out my site on Android 5.0.2 and I can't seem to get the fonts loaded correctly. I am wondering if I am using this font-face wrong. Have a look see:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'AgencyFB-Reg';
  src: url('fonts/AgencyFB-Reg.eot') ;
  src: url('fonts/AgencyFB-Reg.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
       url('fonts/AgencyFB-Reg.woff') format('woff'), 
       url('fonts/AgencyFB-Reg.ttf')  format('truetype'), 
       url('fonts/AgencyFB-Reg.svg#AgencyFB-Reg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your css style where you say the font face

Comment: the css file loads correctly as everything else in the file loads

Comment: what is the url? do you know if it works on ios or Windowsphone?